# assets not being used with Heroku and Cloudflare

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

I have `ruby on rails 6` app that is running on heroku and I am setting it up to run on a custom domain.  I done the following

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
heroku domains:add example.com
heroku domains # noted the herokudns.com names for www.example.com and example.com
# in cloudflare added cnames for www.example.com and example.com
# in cloudflare, checked the example.com cname is flattened
heroku config:set APPLICATION_HOST=www.example.com
heroku config:set ASSET_HOST=www.example.com
```

When I access `www.example.com` I see the raw html, but no styling. But in the log I see

```
2020-08-22T05:42:36.262127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/packs/js/application-aaf9d9c806bf765590e6.js" host=www.example.com request_id=e833945b-54bc-4d4a-bbf7-d7c502444b15 fwd="2001:8003:2d82:b901:5821:c882:4a71:5ba0,108.162.250.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=302 protocol=https
2020-08-22T05:42:36.261767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-90a7667ebe1530b7281dc7743ca54268ab23286f578c9a356684ecd84321b0fd.css" host=www.example.com request_id=d2ffabfa-fe6e-4ef9-b6a4-d8bd771181dc fwd="2001:8003:2d82:b901:5821:c882:4a71:5ba0,108.162.250.69" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=331 protocol=https
```

If I look at the source code for page in the `<head>` tag I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://www.philomaths.org/assets/application-90a7667ebe1530b7281dc7743ca54268ab23286f578c9a356684ecd84321b0fd.css" />
    <script src="https://www.philomaths.org/packs/js/application-aaf9d9c806bf765590e6.js"></script>
```

So, the correct asset files are being loaded. But when I view the asset files, both the js and css are empty.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a minor change and pushed it to heroku to make sure it was compiling properly, and I saw this message

```
remote:        You set `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile'` in production,
remote:        but you do not have `apache` installed on this app. This setting will cause any assets
remote:        being served by your application to be returned without a body.
remote:        
remote:        To fix this issue, please set:
remote:        
remote:        config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil
```

I realised I had incorrectly set `the x_sendfile_header`. I fixed it in production.rb and
then pushed it to heroku, but still the same problem.

I then used the `heroku repo:reset` and `heroku repo:purge_cache` command, reset the Cloudflare cache, and cleared my browser cache, and ... it is now working!